# Dispatch 2 actions in redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux

When I click a button and trigger onClick function. First, I dispatch to createRentalInfo action and it's update rentalInfo to reducer. After that, I continuously dispatch createBill action and I need id from rentalInfo for parameter in createBill. How can I get that id in the best way?

```
dispatch(createRentalInfo(...));
dispatch(createBill({rentalId: ??? ,...})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can let thunks return values, it's useful for coordinating async work in components: https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#returning-values-from-thunks

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const createRentalInfoAndBill = useCallback(
    async () => {
        const rentalId = await dispatch(createRentalInfo(...));
        dispatch(createBill({ rentalId, ... });
    },
    [dispatch]
);

return <button onClick={createRentalInfoAndBill} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let rentalInfo = useSelector((state)=>state.reducerState.rentalInfo)
dispatch(createBill({rentalId: rentalInfo.id ,...})
```

after first dispatch you are updating rentalInfo state and then you can access that state by useSelector and pass it to your second dispatch

Comment: I know. But I do dispatch 2 actions when I click the button. So I useSelector to get id from rentalInfo it returned undefined actually

Comment: you need to add a check like (rentalInfo?.id). useSelector gives you undefined at first when you update reducer state, you can console log the bheavior after 1-2 consoles rendered you will get your updated state.